# position absolute inside flexbox vs inside block in span element

Tags: css, css-transitions, tailwind-css

If I change the display property position `flex` to `block`, why does the position of the `span` element (which is in green with `position:absolute`) change? There is no element with `position:relative` here.
So doesn't it position itself at the parent corner by default?
Why is it in second position if the parent's display property is `block`?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: With `position: absolute` the element is taken out of the natural flow of the container and is placed at the upper left corner of the parent container. Normally the parent container has a `position: relative` to accomplish this but I can't see that your container has that.

Comment: @Laisender  thank you for reply
but my question is i only chnage position of parent display:flex to display:block. than why place of green box is changed ??
does't it should only in top corner of parent in both cases. because i dont add position:relative to any of component.

Comment: According to me, some other property is getting set on the parent or child element. I have also tried to do the same thing, but didn't get the same behaviour as you described. Try it on a newly created page without using any framework.

Comment: @Puspam Thank you for you effort. 
https://codepen.io/meet-vaghasiya/pen/wvyxzQB
just comment and uncomment third like in css which is display: flex. and see how green block was changing. does't it will be on top left corner in both case ?